# Using webview in android, want to go from one html page to another but error occurs

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview in my android project. The app starts with the page I want i.e. file.html (as shown below in Webview code).

But the issue is that when I click on "NEXT PAGE!" button in my file.html, it should redirect me to file1.html. But the app stops by saying that "the file must have been renamed, moved or deleted". The file (file.html) works fine on browser. It redirect me to file1.html perfectly. I am using Android Studio. Can anyone tell me what mistake I have did?

My webview code part is shown below:

```
//Webview Code:
WebView myWebView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
    }
```

The code of the file.html (file which open when app starts) is shown below:

```
<!--file.html Code-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagegradient">
        <a href="file1.html" class="button width-200px"><span>NEXT PAGE!</span></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my assets folder looks like this

```
---> assets ---> file1.html

            ---> file2.html

            ---> file.html
```

Stacktrace of logcat window:

```
12-25 18:06:19.643 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:13(114:155); file:external/openssl/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:142;Function:ASN1_get_object
12-25 18:06:28.846 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{7c75e64 com.example.mnm.papp}}
12-25 18:06:28.847 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}
12-25 18:06:29.121 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@239c34c9, appName=com.example.mnm.papp, pkg=com.example.mnm.papp, comp={com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.example.mnm.papp-1/base.apk
12-25 18:06:30.124 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@48446e1,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@2cf0ec06
12-25 18:06:29.925 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
12-25 18:06:29.928 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
12-25 18:06:29.942 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
12-25 18:06:29.998 20937-21126/com.example.mnm.papp W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
12-25 18:06:30.003 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
12-25 18:06:30.004 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=43 off=46092 len=2953
12-25 18:06:30.006 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:44 off:228796 len:643667
12-25 18:06:30.028 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (0/0x5/0x6/0x4)
12-25 18:06:30.028 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (720/1280/1)
12-25 18:06:30.286 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}
12-25 18:06:30.123 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [system]: current 37 != cached 0
12-25 18:06:30.139 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/PasswordDatabase: constructor password.db
12-25 18:06:30.171 20937-21132/com.example.mnm.papp W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
12-25 18:06:30.185 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
12-25 18:06:30.201 20937-21147/com.example.mnm.papp D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
12-25 18:06:30.205 20937-21147/com.example.mnm.papp D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
12-25 18:06:30.535 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}
12-25 18:06:30.535 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
12-25 18:06:30.578 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
12-25 18:06:30.578 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}
12-25 18:06:30.579 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}
12-25 18:06:35.883 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}
12-25 18:06:35.908 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493
12-25 18:06:35.911 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
12-25 18:06:38.929 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{33fdd8cd token=android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493 {com.example.mnm.papp/com.example.mnm.papp.MainActivity}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@3363cd4a
12-25 18:06:38.931 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@271f5493
```

The red line in these stacktrace are:

```
12-25 18:06:30.028 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (0/0x5/0x6/0x4)
12-25 18:06:30.028 20937-20937/com.example.mnm.papp E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (720/1280/1)
```

Comment: can you post full stacktrace of exception?

Comment: It works fine when I run it on AVD, but the same issue exist when I run this in my android mobile

Comment: no stacktrace = no help. sorry

Comment: @snachmsm I have added the stacktrace above. Kindly check it

Comment: stacktrace of exception, there is no exception in posted logcat. "red lines" doesn't mean that this is exception